# How do I get a better preview for archives in ranger?

Tags: linux, archiving, ranger

I'm not a fan of the default preview for archives in Ranger, and I want to change it.

As an example, for `.zip` files, the preview displays the plain output of `unzip -l <file>`. Using custom commands however, it's possible to display a tree view of the archive (as an example, `.zip` files can be viewed as a tree with `unzip -l <file> | awk 'FNR>3 {$1=$2=$3=""; print substr($0,4)}' | tree --fromfile`.

How do I configure Ranger to preview/display the archive file with a custom shell command for each filetype (`.tar.gz`, `.zip`, `.7z`, etc...)?

---

Related: [How do I get a better exploration for archives in ranger?](https://superuser.com/q/1729772/1497993)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preview is defined in `.config/ranger/scope.sh`. If it does not exist in you configuration, run `ranger --copy-config=scope` in your shell, and it'll pop up in your `.config` folder.

After that, you can change the `scope.sh` file as you please. In the specific examples of archives, you can change the `handle_extension` function.

Here are some examples that will display `.tar.gz`, `.zip`, and `.7z` files as trees in the preview:

```bash
tar|gz)
    tar -tf "${FILE_PATH}" | tree --fromfile && exit 5
    exit 1;;
zip)
    unzip -l -- "${FILE_PATH}" | awk 'FNR>3 {$1=$2=$3=""; print substr($0,4)}' | tree --fromfile && exit 5
    exit 1;;
7z)
    # This awk script finds out which character column "Name" is at.
    awk_script='{if (ix == 0) {ix = index($0, "Name");}p = (body == 1);if (ix > 0) {body = (body + ($0 ~ / *-[ -]+/)) % 2;}if (p == 1 && body == 1) {print ix;}}'
    7z l "${FILE_PATH}" | awk 'FNR>20 {print $0}' | head -n -2 | cut -c$(7z l "${FILE_PATH}" | awk "$awk_script")- | tree --fromfile && exit 5
    exit 1;;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).