# How do I get a better exploration for archives in ranger?

Tags: linux, archiving, ranger

I'm not a fan of the default exploration for archives in Ranger, which resumes to showing the output of `atool` when opening the file.

I found out [this `avfs` config](https://github.com/SL-RU/ranger-config/blob/master/avfs.py), which allows you to explore an archive in ranger with the `:avfs` command. However, I want to be able to explore the archive just like a normal folder, and enter it by pressing <kbd>l</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd>.

Is there a way to configure Ranger to execute the `:avfs` command when opening these archives (i.e. when pressing <kbd>l</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd> on them)?

---

Related: [How do I get a better preview for archives in ranger?](https://superuser.com/q/1729515/1497993)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute a *ranger command* upon opening a file, there's a bit of a hack that you can use. That is remapping the <kbd>l</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd> keys to execute it with a bit of python. You should do this in `.config/ranger/rc.conf`.

Here's an example that will execute [`:avfs`](https://github.com/SL-RU/ranger-config/blob/master/avfs.py) for the filetypes `.tar.gz`, `.zip`, and `.7z`:

```
map l eval fm.execute_console('avfs') if fm.thisfile.extension in ['zip', 'tar', 'gz', '7z'] else fm.move(right=1)

map <RIGHT> eval fm.execute_console('avfs') if fm.thisfile.extension in ['zip', 'tar', 'gz', '7z'] else fm.move(right=1)
```

If you want to configure a *shell command* to explore the file in a program outside of ranger, you're looking at `.config/ranger/rifle.conf`. If you don't know how to configure it, I recommend reading the [default rifle.conf](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/blob/master/ranger/config/rifle.conf). There's a big comment at the beginning explaining how to use it, and it's full good examples.